# Image size optimisation in Linux

Tags: linux, image, optimization

There is a Yahoo "Smush.it" service that allow to optimise image size.
I am looking for alternative way to reach the same goal using Linux application.
A lot of images need to processed and uploading them manually one by one seems not a good idea.

How such can be done in Linux ?

Comment: [lwn](http://lwn.net/Articles/619330/) mentions recent `gthumb`; you might look inside its source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jpegs I use JPEGmini and from what I tested it's the one with the best results keeping the same visible image quality while reducing a lot of the size, they have a server version for Linux which is not cheap and I never used.

There's also Mozilla's [mozjpeg](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg/releases/tag/v2.0) which you can use directly from the terminal, but it also reduces image quality.

In some tests I did, mozjpeg gives smaller files (*not much*) than JPEGmini's, but with lower image quality.

If you need to reduce pngs, you could try [Trimage](http://alternativeto.net/software/trimage/) or some of the alternatives listed on the same link.

Smush.it's FAQ lists all the tools they are using in their service.